# Span different number of columns on different rows

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, wpf-controls

I am trying to show a UI that looks like the following.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
-    Label Along With Some Awesome Text       - Label -
- ------------                                ---------
- Picture    -  All of the rest of my text would      -                                 
--------------                                        -             
- start up there and go on down to here and then it   -     
- would keep going and end up as a .....              -
-                                                     -
-                                                     -
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried using a grid control, the top labels at 0,0 and 0,1 with a span of 0.

But for the Block of text I can't figure out a way to start at column 1 on row 2, and then start at column 0 on row 3, if that makes sense?

Comment: Is this dynamic text you are bringing into the UI at runtime, or static text you are defining in the Xaml itself?

Comment: dyanimc text, its actually property bound...binding...?

Comment: One of those things that is easy in HTML but seems very hard in XAML.  You might want to take a look at `RichTextBox`, which might do the job -- it supports an inline layout, at least.

Comment: Binding is one way of to achieve that yes.

Comment: I Hope this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529065/preserving-indenting-when-wrapping-in-a-wpf-textblock-control

Comment: @Joseph at first glance it looks promising, but I think it is not the answer. The entire document viewer will still only occupy cell 1,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[Flow Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa970909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And here is a similar question i found.

[Wrapping text around an image or linking two TextBlocks in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339051/wrapping-text-around-an-image-or-linking-two-textblocks-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Comment: I wish I could search this website as good as other people. I am going to put this object into grid row 1 column 0 and this should fix my problem. Thank you.